# Open CD/DVD door with a Windows API call?

Tags: winapi, dvd, cd

How do I open the CD/DVD door with a Windows API call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET this will work:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/15834-eject-close-cd-tray.aspx

It was the first link to come up when I googled "win api open cd door".

This was the second one:
[Windows CDROM Eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670/windows-cdrom-eject).

Comment: Actually I had to do that from Lua. But thanks, your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is interested, here is a short draft of how it can be done in Lua:

```
require ("alien")

local kolbasz = alien.winmm.mciSendStringA
kolbasz:types{ ret = 'long', abi = 'stdcall', 'string', 'string', 'long', 'long'}
kolbasz("set cdaudio door open", null, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, string buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);

//Open
mciSendString("set CDAudio door open", "", 127, IntPtr.Zero);

//Close
mciSendString("set CDAudio door closed", "", 127, IntPtr.Zero);
```