# How to Eject CD-ROM

Tags: c#, cd-rom

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Windows CDROM Eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670/windows-cdrom-eject)
>   [Open CD/DVD door with a Windows API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829342/open-cd-dvd-door-with-a-windows-api-call)

I have looked around and can't find a simple solution to what I want to do.

I want to open a CD-Rom from my C# app. It should check if the media is in fact a cd- rom and then open it. Is there a quick solution to this or am I missing something?

Comment: Answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829342/open-cd-dvd-door-with-a-windows-api-call

Comment: [This answer][1] should get you on the right track.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670/windows-cdrom-eject

Comment: You already have the technical solution, and to further answer your question you need to make a call to a native API so your application won't be entirely consistent of managed code.

Comment: do accept answer if it works for you

Comment: Why is this question not closed as a duplicate? And/or why was it re-opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this URL, it has both managed and unmanaged code for .net

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273513-how-eject-cd-rom-c

Try below code :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace EjectMedia
{
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     // My CDROM is on drive E:
         EjectMedia.Eject(@"\\.\E:");
    }
}

class EjectMedia
{
         // Constants used in DLL methods
         const uint GENERICREAD = 0x80000000;
         const uint OPENEXISTING = 3;
         const uint IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA = 2967560;
         const int INVALID_HANDLE = -1;

         // File Handle
         private static IntPtr fileHandle;
         private static uint returnedBytes;
         // Use Kernel32 via interop to access required methods
         // Get a File Handle
         [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
         static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string fileName,
         uint desiredAccess,
         uint shareMode,
         IntPtr attributes,
         uint creationDisposition,
         uint flagsAndAttributes,
         IntPtr templateFile);
         [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
         static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr driveHandle);
         [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
         static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr driveHandle,
         uint IoControlCode,
         IntPtr lpInBuffer,
         uint inBufferSize,
         IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
         uint outBufferSize,
         ref uint lpBytesReturned,
                  IntPtr lpOverlapped);

public static void Eject(string driveLetter)
{
         try
         {         
           // Create an handle to the drive
          fileHandle = CreateFile(driveLetter,
           GENERICREAD,
           0,
           IntPtr.Zero,
           OPENEXISTING,
           0,
            IntPtr.Zero);
         if ((int)fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE)
         {
          // Eject the disk
          DeviceIoControl(fileHandle,
           IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA,
           IntPtr.Zero, 0,
           IntPtr.Zero, 0,
           ref returnedBytes,
                  IntPtr.Zero);
          }
         }
         catch
         {
                  throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
         }
         finally
         {
                  // Close Drive Handle
                  CloseHandle(fileHandle);
                  fileHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
         }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Comment: Well, if there is no DVD in the drive it works to open the door, otherwise doesn't seem to work.