# Programmatically opening the CD tray

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a small program in C# in Windows that would open the CD drive tongue - eject the CD if there is one.  I'd like to know where to start with this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670/windows-cdrom-eject

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Opening and closing a disk drive programmatically in C# is not all that difficult thanks to a useful API function called mciSendStringA.

First you will need to define the function that will be opening the disk tray:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendString")]
public static extern int mciSendStringA(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, 
                            int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
```

If the code above does not compile try adding the following C# line at the very top of your source code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

**Opening the Disk Drive**

To open the disk drive you need to send two command strings using mciSendStringA. The first one will assign a name to the desired drive. The second command will actually open the disk tray:

```
mciSendStringA("open " + driveLetter + ": type CDaudio alias drive" + driveLetter, 
                 returnString, 0, 0);
mciSendStringA("set drive" + driveLetter + " door open", returnString, 0, 0);
```

**Closing the Disk Drive**

To close the disk drive you need to send two command strings once again. The first one will be the same. The second command will now close the disk tray:

```
mciSendStringA("open " + driveLetter + ": type CDaudio alias drive" + driveLetter, 
                 returnString, 0, 0);
mciSendStringA("set drive" + driveLetter + " door closed", returnString, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was interested in learning more of these API's. Do you know good tutorials?