# Eject Memory card from Card Reader C#

Tags: c#, usb

I have a custom developed USB card reader. I am using the following code to interact and iterrate over the device:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx

The code above provides an 'eject' method using the following line:

```
Native.CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi(device.InstanceHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, 0, 0);
```

However this 'eject' method unmounts the entire drive instead of simply ejecting the media card.

Why this is a problem is because I want to 'eject' the media card, then put in a different one. However when the whole reader is ejected i have to unplug/replug the device for it to show back up.

In windows explorer when I right click 'eject' it operates as I am imagining, where it safely removes the memory card but not the card reader.

How can I go about implementing this different type of eject in c#?

Answer (score 1):

I came here accidentally while doing a search on "CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi", and saw that it was similar to a solution I'd recently done by pulling together similar pieces of a solution. Forgive the late answers.

Here's what worked for me (this also addresses some issues I've seen on other SO questions regarding `AutoEjectVolume` from the Microsoft sample not "doing everything" that the system does when you Safely Remove Hardware using the OS):

1. Start with the steps outlined in [**How to Eject Removable Media in Windows**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/165721).
2. Replace the call to `AutoEjectVolume` with code that is, in effect, the body of the `RemoveDrive` method from [**How to Prepare a USB Drive for Safe Removal**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375916/How-to-Prepare-a-USB-Drive-for-Safe-Removal). Note that this later work relies heavily on two other CodeProject articles — including the one you referenced in your question — ported to C#.

In 2, I say "in effect" because — in practice — you use the same `hVolume` in both solutions, and it makes more sense to do all the checks in the CodeProject `RemoveDrive` method *before* calling `LockVolume`, `DismountVolume`, or `PrepareRemovalOfVolume` in the Microsoft solution, and *then* call `CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi` as shown in the CodeProject solution.

A short pseudo-code summary:

- Open the volume with `CreateFile` (CodeProject)
- Obtain drive's device instance handle and drive's parent's device
  instance handle (CodeProject)
- Exit before calling — in particular — `DismountVolume`,
  if any of the steps above fail (CodeProject)
- Call `LockVolume`, `DismountVolume`, and `PrepareRemovalOfVolume`
  using the `hVolume` returned from `CreateFile` (Microsoft)
- You can close the `hVolume` at any time after this
- Call `CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi` on the drive's parent's device
  instance handle (CodeProject)