# c# Eject USB - code for LockVolume, DismountVolume, and PrepareRemovalOfVolume

Tags: c#, file, usb

I am struggling trying to create an application capable to eject any USB mass storage device.
After many tries, I am finally using some code found in codeproject
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375916/How-to-Prepare-a-USB-Drive-for-Safe-Removal
BUT with some USB devices I get an error "This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again.". I dont really understand why it happens for some devices and not for others...

The error window is shown and basically removalDrive() method returns false, USB not ejected.

```
        public static bool RemoveDrive( string driveCharWithColon )
    {
        // open the storage volume
        IntPtr hVolume = CreateFile( @"\\.\" + driveCharWithColon, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero );
        if ( hVolume.ToInt32( ) == -1 ) return false;

        // get the volume's device number
        long DeviceNumber = GetDeviceNumber( hVolume );
        if ( DeviceNumber == -1 ) return false;

        // get the drive type which is required to match the device numbers correctely
        string rootPath = driveCharWithColon + "\\";        
        DriveType driveType = GetDriveType( rootPath );

        // get the dos device name (like \device\floppy0) to decide if it's a floppy or not - who knows a better way?
        StringBuilder pathInformation = new StringBuilder( 250 );
        uint res = QueryDosDevice( driveCharWithColon, pathInformation, 250 );
        if ( res == 0 ) return false;

        // get the device instance handle of the storage volume by means of a SetupDi enum and matching the device number
        long DevInst = GetDrivesDevInstByDeviceNumber( DeviceNumber, driveType, pathInformation.ToString( ) );
        if ( DevInst == 0 ) return false;

        // get drives's parent, e.g. the USB bridge, the SATA port, an IDE channel with two drives!
        int DevInstParent = 0;
        CM_Get_Parent( ref DevInstParent, ( int ) DevInst, 0 );

        for ( int tries=1; tries <= 3; tries++ )  // sometimes we need some tries...
        {
            int r = CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi( DevInstParent, IntPtr.Zero, null, 0, 0 );
            if ( r == 0 ) return true;
            Thread.Sleep( 500 );
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Reading more answers I found this one 
[Eject Memory card from Card Reader C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989844/eject-memory-card-from-card-reader-c-sharp/48792411?noredirect=1#comment84587162_48792411)

Where it is mentioned that before invoking the method CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi, I have to call "LockVolume, DismountVolume, and PrepareRemovalOfVolume" using the hVolume returned from CreateFile.

Unfortunately these functions are only provided by Microsoft in C++.
[how-to-ejecting-removable-media-in-windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/165721/how-to-ejecting-removable-media-in-windows-nt-windows-2000-windows-xp)

I wanted to try this solution but I dont really know how to implement those methods using c#.

Any could give me any idea about what might be happening?
I tried with simply closing the file handler

```
CloseHandle(hVolume);
```

before calling the method CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi but it created other SEHException exception (External component has thrown an exception).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to implemented in C# the 3 methods but the methods LockVolume and DismountVolume always return a false value.

```
    const int LOCK_TIMEOUT = 10000;       // 10 Seconds
    const int LOCK_RETRIES = 20; 
    public static bool LockVolume(IntPtr hVolume)
    {
        int dwBytesReturned;
        int dwSleepAmount;
        int nTryCount;
        dwSleepAmount = LOCK_TIMEOUT / LOCK_RETRIES;
        // Do this in a loop until a timeout period has expired
        for (nTryCount = 0; nTryCount < LOCK_RETRIES; nTryCount++)
        {
            if (DeviceIoControl(hVolume,
                                FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                out dwBytesReturned,
                                IntPtr.Zero))
                return true;
            Thread.Sleep(dwSleepAmount);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool PreventRemovalOfVolume(IntPtr hVolume, bool fPreventRemoval)
    {
        int retVal;
        IntPtr buffer = new IntPtr((fPreventRemoval) ? 1 : 0);
        return DeviceIoControl(hVolume, IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL, buffer, 1, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out retVal, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    public static bool DismountVolume(IntPtr hVolume)
    {
        int dwBytesReturned;

        return DeviceIoControl(hVolume,
                                FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME,
                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                out dwBytesReturned,
                                IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public static bool  AutoEjectVolume(IntPtr hVolume)
    {
        int  dwBytesReturned;

        return DeviceIoControl(hVolume,
                                IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA,
                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                                out dwBytesReturned,
                                IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public static bool CloseVolume(IntPtr hVolume)
    {
        return CloseHandle(hVolume);
    }
```

UPDATE:
I captured the error produced in the DeviceIoControl call using the code

```
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

and I got error 6, meaning ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. :O

Now I am even more confused as that handler works fine in the rest of the RemoveDrive method, including the CloseVolume(handler) call.

```
        public static bool RemoveDrive(string driveCharWithColon)
    {
        // open the storage volume
        IntPtr hVolume = CreateFile(@"\\.\" + driveCharWithColon, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hVolume.ToInt32() == -1) return false;

        // get the volume's device number
        long DeviceNumber = GetDeviceNumber(hVolume);
        if (DeviceNumber == -1) return false;

        // get the drive type which is required to match the device numbers correctely
        string rootPath = driveCharWithColon + "\\";
        DriveType driveType = GetDriveType(rootPath);

        // get the dos device name (like \device\floppy0) to decide if it's a floppy or not - who knows a better way?
        StringBuilder pathInformation = new StringBuilder(250);
        uint res = QueryDosDevice(driveCharWithColon, pathInformation, 250);
        if (res == 0) return false;

        // get the device instance handle of the storage volume by means of a SetupDi enum and matching the device number
        long DevInst = GetDrivesDevInstByDeviceNumber(DeviceNumber, driveType, pathInformation.ToString());
        if (DevInst == 0) return false;

        // get drives's parent, e.g. the USB bridge, the SATA port, an IDE channel with two drives!
        int DevInstParent = 0;
        CM_Get_Parent(ref DevInstParent, (int)DevInst, 0);

        // Lock and dismount the volume.
        bool e = LockVolume(hVolume);
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        bool f = DismountVolume(hVolume);
        int error2 = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        // Close the volume so other processes can use the drive.
        if (!CloseVolume(hVolume))
            return false;

        for (int tries = 1; tries <= 3; tries++)  // sometimes we need some tries...
        {
            int r = CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi(DevInstParent, IntPtr.Zero, null, 0, 0);
            if (r == 0) return true;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        return false;
    }
```