# How to find out is storage volume on usb ejected or not?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an USB device with CD Drive and storage volume. I can eject both of them or one by one. 
When I call `CreateFileA` to obtain handle of ejected volume, it returns a valid handle.

Have anyone idea, how to detect that volume is not ready for using?

UDP: I have an application, that can starts when the volume is already ejected. I want to identify state of the volume, when programm is running

Comment: Please check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918248/how-to-eject-a-usb-removable-disk-volume-similar-to-the-eject-function-in-win?rq=1) to see if it solves your issue. Specifically, the answer about setting the correct access when using `CreateFile`.

Comment: @Das_Geek, `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_MOUNTED` for any cases returns non zero value, which means the volume is currently mounted. (But not plugged in, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

A message of `WM_DEVICECHANGE` will notify applications of volume arrival and removal.
Find the `dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`.

There's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/DevIO/detecting-media-insertion-or-removal) on msdn.

Comment: I want to identify the current state (not event)

Comment: You can monitor the event and then modify the global variables for subsequent judgment.