# C# How to tell if DVD drive tray is open?

Tags: c#, winapi, dvd

I have a DVD reading and burning app in C#. I want to be able to detect the difference between an empty drive (no disk) and an open drive.

Edit: After some more googling, I think a better problem description is "**I want to access the drive tray status - open or closed**"

I can use

```
ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType= 5")
```

to find all the dvd drives in the system, and the properties tell me if there is a disk in the drive. `Access` property tells me if there is a blank disk.

But `Access` is null when the drive is open, and when the drive is shut and empty. And I don't see any other property that changes when the drive opens or closes.

Anyone know a way to distinguish an open drive from a closed and empty drive?

I am using Win7, but ideally the solution would work on XP and Vista also.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969435/check-cd-rom-tray-status

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: Why? that question do not have an answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you can do that. What should it return for a slot in drive, for example?

Comment: I could live with it failing in that case, Michael. The drive must know if its open or closed. And you can open and shut the drive using c# - so it must be possible to access tray status.

Answer (score 5):

MediaLoaded property (Win32_CDROMDrive) will tell you whether you have a disc loaded. I am bit confused what you are looking for:

1. disk tray open
2. disk tray closed - no media
3. disk tray closed - has media

MediaLoaded property will help in case 2 (False) and 3 (True)

Comment: BTW MediaLoaded is available on Win32_CDROMDrive object

Comment: I wish to distinguish between 1 and 2. As in I want to tell if the drive is open or if the drive is closed and empty.

Comment: TargetInstance property can be used. Once disc is ejected it will be null. If disc is loaded it will not be null

Comment: Hi Lokeshwer. What value will TargetInstance have if there is no disk and the drive is closed?

Comment: I understand the problem. So I am not sure if we can infer directly with WMI objects

Answer (score 1):

[IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try, once I figure out how in c#. But from reading it sounds like this param will tell me the size of a drive - I don't understand how it could tell me whether a DVD drive is open or empty?

Comment: Not sure if Stijn's solution is best, but reading the docs you could handle the error condition:
If the operation fails or is pending, DeviceIoControl returns zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Comment: @Sugrue I can't try it out right now, but I assume the sizes of an empty drive (0 or null) and an open drive (700MB or a different value) will be different.