# detect which application opened the CD-ROM

Tags: winapi, native, cd-rom

I need to write a function to detect the application name that issued a cd-rom open. Basically I need to listen to DriverChangedEvents in windows(which I know how to do). What I need your help is how to figure out the application name that sent the request to open cd-rom

Comment: By CDROM open, do you mean "eject"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper winmm.dll for your system which wraps all access to the real winmm.dll. Then look for calls to mciSendString() with arguments like "set cdaudio door open" and "set cdaudio door closed".

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670/windows-cdrom-eject).

An example of [how to wrap a Windows DLL](http://sol.gfxile.net/ddhack/) in your own. The [source for said example](https://code.google.com/p/ddhack/).